# Install Hard Drive without format or delete partitions

Tags: 12.04, server, hard-drive

I am pretty noob on ubuntu server, but I can't find an answer.

I had an ubuntu server in a machine, with a HDD with the OS, and another HDD with data.

The HDD with the OS get broken, so I replaced it.

I installed the same ubuntu server in a new HDD, and I would like to plug the data HDD, but I am scared that ubuntu would try to format it. What is the way to plug it and indicate ubuntu to use it, without loosing the data? I understand that the partitions are OK because it comes from another ubuntu.

Backup is not an option, as this is my biggest HDD, and I dont have enought space to save all the data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No worries. Ubuntu will not try to reformat any disk plugged in. Its very friendly with data and disk management.

Nothing will be changed without user permission.

Power off your system, plugin your HDD and boot. By default it will be automatically detected.

In case it doesnt, do:

1. `fdisk -l` look for the disk device name.
2. `mount /dev/sdb1 /mountpoint` /dev/sdb1 is just an example it might vary in your setup.
3. Browse the HDD in file manager.

Since you mentioned the disk is from Ubuntu, then expect that the filesystem type will be automatically detected by `mount`.